# AD Powershell and IPPhone

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes, export

with AD and power shell why when i do

```
Get-ADUser -Identity street -Properties *
```

do i see the ipphone attribute

but if I do `get-aduser -filter * -properties * | export-csv .....`

no IP phone gets exported to the CSV file?

Comment: Hi, did you tried to run your code by selecting 'ipphone' after 'Properties' switch? Like this get-aduser -filter * -properties ipphone

Comment: that works but I want all properties not just ipphone. So i could put a long list after properties but this would be messy.

Comment: also with the second comand if i leave of the "export-csv" then in the powershell window I see the ipphone returned. just not in the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your script, just before exporting it to csv select all like this:

`get-aduser -filter * -properties * | select * | export-csv`

Comment: same result. ipphone does not apper in output

Comment: OH I never tried -properties ipphone,* which does seem to work